# Freeing 2D Array of Pointers from a Function in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, free

In C, I have the following function for creating a 2D array.

```
int** createMatrix(int xdim, int ydim){
        int** mat = malloc(xdim*sizeof(int*));

        int i;
        for(i=0; i<xdim; i++){
                mat[i] = malloc(ydim*sizeof(int));
        }

        return mat;
}
```

In the caller function (int main() in this case):

```
int **matA = createMatrix(10, 10);
free(matA);
```

I seemingly have a problem with freeing memory, and I am wondering if this is because the variable "mat" is never freed.

Is it enough to free(matA), as I have done? Or is the issue that I cannot free(mat)?

Comment: both `mat` and `matA` are pointers to the same location, so when you `free(matA)` is as if you would hypothetically `free(mat)` (except that `mat` is not in scope so you can't free it). The problem as sugested in the answers is that you have too free all the allocated memory (that is pointed to by every pointer in `matA`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to free each of the rows individually first (essentially the reverse process of your create)

```
for(i=0; i < xdim; i++)
     free(matA[i]);

free(matA)
```

I would recommend creating a `freeMat` function to do this

Answer (score 2):

Freeing a pointer actually means that you are freeing the memory that it points to for another allocation. So yes, freeing `matA` will free the chunk of memory you allocated but you need to free each of the allocated element of `mat`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < xdim; i++)
    free(matA[i]);
free(matA);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to free only `matA`.  `matA` references the storage for `xdim` pointers to `int`, but each of those pointers references its own separate block of storage.  If you allocate an array of arrays in that way then you must free not only the outer array but also (first) each of the inner arrays.

Answer (score 0):

When you deallocate memory previously allocated for a variable (say, `ptr`), you lose access to it. The `free` function doesn't change the value of `ptr` so it still points to the same location (now invalid).

In case of arrays, you have to go through the array, line by line to free each element you've allocated, before deallocating memory of the variable that points to that elements. All users here tell you the same.

If you free one of `[xdim]` first, you'll lose access to all `[ydim]`s (***memory leak***) on which it was pointing. In other words, you won't be able to free them. The OS on your machine can free it automatically (but there is no guarantee) but it's a good practice to control the process of freeing memory:

```
[ X ]---[ydim]--[ydim]-[ydim] 
[ X ]---[ydim]--[ydim]-[ydim]
[ X ]---[ydim]--[ydim]-[ydim]
```

So it's better to free elements are not "in charge" for other elements. In your case, it's `[ydim]`s. Freeing such elements first, you'll not lose other elements, your `[xdim]`s. Then you can pass through `[xdims]` and free them:

```
// freed `[ydim]` of the first `[xdim]`
[xdim]---[ X ]--[ X ]-[ X ] 
[xdim]---[ X ]--[ X ]-[ X ]
[xdim]---[ X ]--[ X ]-[ X ]

// now you can free all `[xdim]`
[ X ]
[ X ]
[ X ]    

// the `matA` array has been freed
```